# C Function Pointer in C++ Class

Tags: c++, c, function-pointers

So i am a bit confused on what to do and hoping someone can help.
Here is the scenario

We have an API (C) that is provided to us in .C and .H files, and are trying to integrate it into our C++ application with as little modification as possible.

They have function pointers something like defined in one of their header files(i cant post the actual code because its not open source)

```
typedef UINT32 (*Write)(UINT8, UINT8, UINT16)
```

So we have a C++ class that we will call ABC.

Inside the ABC class i have something along the lines of this in the constructor. Where WriteABC is a member function of ABC.

```
Write = &ABC::WriteABC
```

The problem is that this does not match up with the define for the function pointer and wont compile.  So as i understand it the easy way to solve this is to just modify the Function pointer in their API to be something like

```
typedef UINT32 (ABC::*Write)(UINT8, UINT8, UINT16)
```

The next problem with this is that  i get an error saying that ABC is not a class.  Even if i include my ABC.h file for the C++ class it says the same thing.

Hopefully this all makes sense and someone can help im at a bit of a loss.

The biggest problem is that i would like the new Function pointer to have access to the instantiation of my class ABC.  But im not sure how to go about doing this unless the function im pointing to is in my class, but i cant seem to do that without altering the definition of the function pointer from the API, and in modifying that typedef for (*WRITE) to (ABC::*WRITE) now the rest of the API that uses that definition fails...

I seem to be stuck in a loop...

Comment: Did you try `class ABC;` just before your `typedef`?

Comment: If I understood you correctly, you have either the same or a relatively close problem as the one here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2695743/assign-c-instance-method-to-a-global-function-pointer

Comment: The problem is different... Here the OP is trying to create a function pointer the proper c++ way and has an unexplainable compile-time error. Nothing is said about how he called said pointer function.