# Assign std::function object to c function pointer

Tags: c++

I've a C library which provides an API to register callbacks. It goes something like this

In clib.h

```
typedef int (*func_ptr)(int*);
void register_cb(func_ptr rd, func_ptr wr);
```

In clib.c

```
#include "clib.h"

static func_ptr r;
static func_ptr w;

void register_cb(func_ptr rd, func_ptr wr)
{
    r = rd;
    w = wr;
}

int main()
{
    int b = 12;
    if (r)
        r(&b);
    if (w)
        w(&b);
    return 0;
}
```

I have to pass class member functions as call backs to this C library. I'm trying to do something like this

In MyClass.hpp

```
class MyClass {
    private:
        int v;
    public:
        int read (int *val)
        {
            *val = v;
            return 0;
        }

        int write (int *val)
        {
            v = *val;
            return 0;
        }
};

void reg_callbacks ();
int rd (MyClass &mc, int* a);
int wr (MyClass &mc, int* a);
```

In test.cpp, there is a global object of type MyClass. I'm trying to pass memeber functions of MyClass to the C library using the global object

```
#include "MyClass.hpp"
#include "clib.h"
#include <functional>

MyClass mc;
using fp = std::function<int(int*)>;

void reg_callbacks ()
{
    using namespace std::placeholders;
    fp r = std::bind(rd, mc, _1);
    fp w = std::bind(wr, mc, _1);
    register_cb(r.target<func_ptr>(), w.target<func_ptr>());
}

int rd (MyClass &mc, int* a)
{
    return mc.read(a);
}

int wr (MyClass &mc, int *a)
{
    return mc.write(a);
}
```

When I try to compile test.cpp now, I get this error

```
$ g++ -std=c++11 -c test.cpp
test.cpp: In function _void reg_callbacks()_:
test.cpp:14:59: error: cannot convert _int (**)(int*)_ to _func_ptr {aka int (*)(int*)}_ for argument _1_ to _void register_cb(func_ptr, func_ptr)_
     register_cb(r.target<func_ptr>(), w.target<func_ptr>());
                                                           ^
```

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong here? Is there better way to pass member functions as callbacks to a c library?

Comment: Effectively, you cannot pass C++ objects of any non-POD type to a C library.

Comment: @NeilButterworth There are cases when you can pass them via `void*` such as when they are passed back to you, for example in the case of a callback. You are free to cast that `void*` back to the object's actual type.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39562437/how-do-i-pass-a-stdfunction-object-to-a-function-taking-a-function-pointer

Comment: @Francois I don't see how that will work inside the C library for non-POD types.

Comment: @NeilButterworth It works then the library doesn't use the pointer other than to pass it back to you.

Comment: @Francois Obviously. This is the sort of thing that gives pedantry a bad name.

Comment: @NeilButterworth Well, I don't feel it was pedantic. It's passing a pointer to a non-POD type to a C library and it does come up quite a bit. To each his own I guess.

Comment: Solution to this problem helped me.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2695743/assign-c-instance-method-to-a-global-function-pointer?rq=1

Since mc is global I need not pass it to `rd` and `wr` functions. So I changed the function signatures

`int rd (int* a) {return mc.read(a);}`
`int wr (int *a) {return mc.write(a);}`

Answer (score 0):

Solution to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2695743/assign-c-instance-method-to-a-global-function-pointer?rq=1) problem helped me.  Since mc is global I need not pass it to `rd` and `wr` functions.

In MyClass.hpp

```
class MyClass {
    private:
        int v;
    public:
        int read (int *val)
        {
            *val = v;
            return 0;
        }

        int write (int *val)
        {
            v = *val;
            return 0;
        }
};

void reg_callbacks ();
int rd (int* a);
int wr (int* a);
```

In test.cpp

```
#include "MyClass.hpp"
#include "clib.h"                                                                                                                                                                                          

MyClass mc;                                                                                                                                                                                                 

void reg_callbacks ()                                                                                                                                                                                       
{                                                                                                                                                                                                           
    register_cb(rd, wr);                                                                                                                                                                                    
}                                                                                                                                                                                                           

int rd (int* a)                                                                                                                                                                                             
{                                                                                                                                                                                                           
    return mc.read(a);                                                                                                                                                                                      
}                                                                                                                                                                                                           

int wr (int *a)                                                                                                                                                                                             
{                                                                                                                                                                                                           
    return mc.write(a);                                                                                                                                                                                     
}
```